# Laravel authorization using Gate performance

Tags: laravel

In the document it is suggested to define `Gate` inside `boot` method of the `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` .

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
 
    Gate::define('view-payments', function (SomeModel $someModel) {
        return $someModel->isPaymentsAllowed ? true : false;
    });
}
```

As you can see `SomeModel` model is being called on every request to `HTTP web server`. Is not it is bad to assign `permission` on every page load?

Is there any functionality provided by the `laravel` that i can assign permission in session at the time of login so that `permission` can be fetched through out the application using session without calling `Model` at every subsequent request?

Comment: Did you try it? On login, set `session()->put('isPaymentsAllowed', $someModel->isPaymentsAllowed)`, then check it in your `Gate` via `return session()->get('isPaymentsAllowed', false);`; if that works, then you have your answer.

Comment: the guard will be getting the User (Authenticatable) from the database provider on every request, putting data in the session isn't stopping that from happening ... the session is only holding an identifier for this entity